# Am I on the right track- Unity C# Events at a certain time

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-engine

let me know if i'm on the right track of this-- i want to trigger certain events at a certain time in the game. For instance say at 10AM each morning I will have event a, b, and c happen.
My current code is something like:

```
public static Action<int> morningEvents = delegate { };
```

so I declare an action and then some methods to check time and trigger the action; for example

```
void CheckTime()
{
  check if current time is 10AM then call morningEvents()
}
```

and I will register the the events a b c to the action

```
morningEvents += event a;
morningEvents +=event b;
morningEvents +=event c;
```

Is it possible to achieve my goals with the logic above? Also I don't know what parameters I need to pass in Action< >. I know the default is int but have no idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use events as in code below, but this is certainly not the best example how to do it. In such "simple example", I wouldn't create events - just for the reason that it is so simple.

```
public class MySampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public delegate void CertainTimeReachedHandler();
    public event CertainTimeReachedHandler tenAmTimeReached;
    private bool wasReachedToday = false;

    void Start()
    {
        tenAmTimeReached += ShowClock();
        tenAmTimeReached += b();
        tenAmTimeReached += c();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var tenAm = DateTime.Today.AddHours(10);

        if( (!wasReachedToday) && (now > tenAm) && (now < tenAm.AddSeconds(1)) )
        {
            wasReachedToday = true;
            tenAmTimeReached?.Invoke();
        }
    }

    private void ShowClock() { }
    private void b() { }
    private void c() { }
}
```

If I would want to create it for "production level", I would create:

- Class that represents relation between condition & time - when it should be fired (DT from, DT to, how many times per day it can be fired, etc.) ~ `TaskDTCondition`
- Class that stores all conditions + stores events for them + invokes those events on condition validity (DT reach) ~ `TaskScheduler`
- In my classes where I want to have such checks, I would call `TaskScheduler`, ask for an event at specific date and register my private method to be invoked on that event.

For the above, there is likely to be existing some library already, try look around a little. Maybe even in Unity framework (that I'm not aware of). Anyway, this is really broad and if you would like to have more details, you would want to put on different SE site.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! Could you explain why I have to compare the time between now and 10 AM? Instead of just trigger the event at say Time.Hour ==10 or something like it

Comment: [`DateTime.Now`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now) represents current time set in PC. I'm using this between, because you are never certain, that you hit this in exact milisecond - game will be loading or have some issue and CPU time will be spent on physics. But also you want to be run at 10am, not at 10:15, 10:25 or so. That is why I've limited the window for 1 second - between `10:00:00` and `10:00:01`, in which it can be activated.

Comment: Apart from that, you can certainly just do `DateTime.Now.Hours == 10` :) but this can be invoked even at `10:59:59` .

Comment: Oh that totally makes sense! Been wondering that since I see people do it a lot. Thanks so much!